# How to prevent slowing down when populating a table?

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish, myisam

I am populating a table from a text file stored on my machine.
There will be around a million records by the end of this, but it's too slow to populate, in fact it took 12 hours to reach 140000 records.
Using a while loop, I extract the needed information for each record, then call this function:

```
 public void populateDB(int pid, String id, String title, String yearPublished, String author, String summary) {

    Papers p = new Papers();
    p.setPid(pid);
    p.setPaperId(id);
    p.setTitle(title);
    p.setYearPublished(yearPublished);
    p.setAuthor(author);
    p.setSummary(summary);
    em.persist(p);
    em.flush();
    System.out.println("Populated paper " + id);

}
```

But this slows down significantly as the number of iterations increases.
I think it has something to do with the cpu usage, which seems limited to 50%. But I don't know how to increase this. Max and min threadpool are set to 10.
How can I stop it from slowing down?

Glassfish  3.1.2.2
[image]

Comment: Stupid questions...is there a transaction involved?  Can you commit the transaction earlier?  Can you perform a batch update?

Comment: calling flush for every single record is going to be incredibly slow.

Comment: also, show your extraction code.

Comment: OMG jthalborn, it became so much faster when I didnt call flush for every record :O I'm not sure if it'll slow down later, trying it out now :) MadProgrammer, my engine is non-transactional.

Answer (score 0):

Having a flush in you loop is not going to be good, and also where you do commits is going to be important.  Another factor to consider is what indexes you have on the Table.  Is it possible to drop them whilst you do the import?  Maybe also look at some batch insert as in

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/

Answer (score 0):

A few tips that might help with performance improvement:

1.
If possible, compress the following seven lines of that perform several method calls to one line?

```
Papers p = new Papers();
p.setPid(pid);
p.setPaperId(id);
p.setTitle(title);
p.setYearPublished(yearPublished);
p.setAuthor(author);
p.setSummary(summary);
```

Replace with

```
Papers p = new Papers(pid, id, title, yearPublished, author, summary); // Saves a lot of cycles.
```

2. Consider doing away with em.flush() and console output on every request. If required, you may want to do it do it inside an if() at certain count, lets say 100.

```
if(count/100 == 0) { // Reducing the number of expensive IOs
em.flush()
System.out.println("Populated paper " + id);
}
```